# How to concat columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have download two data frames, that I want to concat them together (I am not programmer).
I am using Python 2.7.

My code is like this:

```
from pandas_datareader.data import Options
import datetime
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.width',280) # default is 80

aapl = Options('aapl', 'yahoo')
expiry = datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)

data_CALL = aapl.get_call_data(expiry=expiry)
data_PUT = aapl.get_put_data(expiry=expiry)

#The first DataFrame
Q1=data_CALL.iloc[0:5, 0:8]
print(Q1.head())

#The Second DataFrame
Q2=data_PUT.iloc[0:5:, 0:8]
print(Q2.head())


#I got this DataFrame
concat=pd.concat([Q1,Q2])
print(concat)
```

The results looks like:
[image]

I want that my final data frame look like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `concat=pd.concat([Q1,Q2], axis='columns')`? (From documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

Answer (score 0):

your result looks like a result of using `groupby` object. i.e you have grouped your data by `strike` as your grouping attribute.

to do it this way, you need to remove your composite index for each dataframe; from the look of it you have a index of `(Strik, Expiry, Type, Symbol)`.

I can only assume this is set up in your `get_call_data` and `get_put_data` functions as they return dataframes directly. I would suggest that you import
raw dataframe as is without setting any index, at this moment; this way `strike`
will remain as column which you could easily use as your grouping attribute as shown below.

actually grouping is very easy:

```
combined = pd.concat([Q1, Q2])
grouped = combined.groupby('strike')  # single grouping attribute
```

to validate result:

```
for name, group in grouped:
    print name
    print group
```

to manipulate the data (just a few examples here):

```
# 1. using groupby builtin functions

first_group = grouped.first()  # you can do last()
first_strike = grouped.get_group('115')  # return you a dataframe as given by you

# 2. using list

group_list = list(grouped)
first_group = group_list[0]  # return a tuple with 2 elements: name and DataFrame
first_strike_name = group_list[0][0]
first_strike_data = group_list[0][1]
```

you can read more about Python GroupBy [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Answer (score 0):

As per your description  you have two dataframes `Q1 and Q2` and you wanted to concatenate both on `"Strike"` index .
For the same code will be something like these ,

```
Concetenateddf=pd.concat([Q1.set_index('Strike'),Q2.set_index('Strike')], axis=1, join='inner')
```

Now if you will do `Concetenateddf.head()` then you will get similar results as you are expecting  .
[image: concetenated dataframe]